# Event is not defined error in javascript only Firefox

Tags: javascript, validation, firefox, dom-events

I use the following script to validate the text box to enter only numbers and (.) which means it is decimal textbox validation. It was work fine in Internet Explorer and Google Chrome. If I execute the function in FireFox I get the following Error:

> **Event Is not Defined**.

How to solve this?

```
function abc(event) {

        if (event.keyCode > 47 && event.keyCode < 58) {
            return true;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I call this function like this:

```
$('.decimalValidate').live('keypress',function(){
          var decimalid=$(this).attr("id");
          var decimalval=$('#'+decimalid).val();
          var decimalvalidate=abc(decimalval);
          if(decimalvalidate == false)
          return false;
     });
```

I assign this validation for text box like this:

```
input type="text" id="Total" class="abc"
```

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: Do you have any eventListener attached or an onclick event (more code please)

Comment: keypress event  i attached for that

Comment: @xdazz i edit how to call that function?

Comment: @user So you didn't pass event to the function but `decimalval`? Your code won't work in all broswers.

Comment: Your `function abc` seems to be javascript and the `$` is jquery. Are you defining the function before the click is initialized? If not do that and try otherwise it will give the error because in javascript you need to follow the flow one after the other when it is used and called step by step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function abc(event) {
        if(!event)
           event= window.event;

        if (event.keyCode > 47 && event.keyCode < 58) {
            return true;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and

```
$('.decimalValidate').live('keypress',function(e){
                              var decimalid=$(this).attr("id");
                              var decimalval=$('#'+decimalid).val();
                              var decimalvalidate=abc(evt); //keypress event
                              if(decimalvalidate == false)
                              return false;
                         });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('.decimalValidate').live('keypress',function(e){
                              var decimalvalidate=abc(e); //this will point to the event of the keypress.
                              if(decimalvalidate == false)
                              return false;
                         });
```

I am not sure why you did all of the decimalid and decimalval operations, but if you want the event, do as I wrote in the edited code above.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

decimalval is not an Event object, and you have to pass it to the abc function in ordert to find out which key you pressed:

```
$('.decimalValidate').live('keypress',function(ev){
                          var decimalid=$(this).attr("id");
                          var decimalval=$('#'+decimalid).val();
                          var decimalvalidate=abc(ev);
                          if(decimalvalidate == false)
                          return false;
                     });
```

Comment: We should start from the beginning :) What are you trying to do with your code?

Comment: function abc(event) {

        if (event.keyCode > 47 && event.keyCode < 58) {
            return true;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: I mean what the goal is, what you are trying to achieve. Do you have an input and wanna find out which key the user pressed or something like that?

Comment: my goal is validate the textbox for decimal validation.only i enter numbers and . symbol only in that text box.I create the text box.Now i try to create general class for validating.I get the ID and pass the Id value to the function.It was work in IE and Chrome

Comment: So what you want to do is to assure that the user isn't going to enter any character, just numbers or dots, is that it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.decimalValidate').on('keypress',function(event){
     var decimalid       =  $(this).attr("id");
     var decimalval      =  $('#'+decimalid).val();
     var decimalvalidate =  abc(event);

     if(decimalvalidate == false)
        return false;
});



function abc(event) {

        if (event.keyCode > 47 && event.keyCode < 58) {
            return true;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

It helps you..